# REST: Reference an entity with URI or with UUID?

Tags: java, api, rest, many-to-many, associations

I'm creating an API that exposes something similar to group memberships. In effect, I have a `GroupMembership` resource that is exposed at `/groupmembership`.

Now when I want to create a new association between a user and a group, I will `POST` to `/groupmembership`. What I'm curious about is how I should reference the `User` and `Group` resource instances. Do I do it through the URI or do I do it through their UUID? That is, which of these two payloads is valid?

```
POST /groupmembership
{
    user: "http://localhost:8080/user/abcd-def-ghij",
    group: "http://localhost:8080/group/1a2-b3c-4d5"
}
```

or

```
POST /groupmembership
{
    user: "abcd-def-ghij",
    group: "1a2-b3c-4d5"
}
```

I am using Spring HATEOAS and as far as I can tell, there is no way to dereference a link to an entity id, which makes the first approach somewhat problematic. Basically, given a link I want to be able to figure out the UUID that references the entity. But I also don't want to parse the URI since they are supposed to be opaque anyway. So can Spring HATEOAS do that?

With the second approach, I can simply look it up, but I wanted to know which approach makes more sense. One thing that bothers me is that the first thing has the distinct flavor of something that should be handled by the client; i.e., it's the client that follows the URI. It seems like the server should simply be able to handle the UUIDs? But on the other hand, the server fully-controls the structure of the URI, and so it seems like it should know how to dereference the URI to the appropriate entity/resource id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you do not need a payload. Publisch the URL of the created Ressource through the Location header with status code 201.

To answer your question, use the URI.
The client shouldn't compose URIs on his own to get the resources.

Comment: Thank you! I think it makes sense since the URI should uniquely identify a resource anyway.